# How can I open a new flutter project on Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and android studio and have been following a tutorial on creating flutter apps. However, I am not able to create a new flutter project but I am unable to find the button to create the new project. Do I have to install anything else? Thank you so much in advance.

[Android Studio main screen][image: 2]

Comment: I have also correctly downloaded the plugins dart and flutter which I tried showing as screenshots but I was not able to. There are updated to the newest versions and I have tried redownloading them also.

Comment: Did you install flutter sdk and accepted the licenses ?

Comment: I have run flutter doctor with no trouble and have accepted all the licenses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Android Studio 3.2 allow to create project in direct.

So you can create it with Intellij Idea or command flutter create project_name

Comment: thank you so much!!! Have a good day :) This worked!

Answer (score 0):

- First, Go to 'Configure',
- there tap 'Plugins'.
- Find and download Flutter and Dart plugins.
  Now you should have that 'create new Flutter Project' button. You're welcome.

Comment: if you could share the links from Android studio, showing an example of doing it. As your solution could become invalid if Android Studio decides to change the menus.